# C++ ReadProcessMemory buffer always displays 0

Tags: c++, readprocessmemory

my &pTemp

So I think I'm not understanding this quite well. If I'm not mistaken, the pointer value should be stored in pTemp, right?. So, if the base pointer is 0x00001A, shouldn't pTemp display the same thing? I'm really new to C++ and any help would be appreciated!

```
DWORD pointer = baseAddress;
DWORD pTemp;
DWORD pointerAddress;

cout << "Base Address: " << (DWORD*) pointer << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < PointerLevel; i++)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        ReadProcessMemory(handle, (LPVOID)pointer, &pTemp, sizeof(4), NULL);
        cout << "pTemp: " << pTemp << endl;
```

Comment: `sizeof(4)` seems extremely dodgy. Are you just guessing syntax?

Comment: If you want specify the size of a pointer, use sizeof(void*).

Comment: `pTemp` will contain whatever data was read by `ReadProcessMemory`. We have no way to know what that data should be.

Comment: What is the return value of ReadProcessMemory call? Remember to check with GetLastError if return value is 0.

Comment: Are you trying to dereference pointer addresses in the target process?  I mean, something like p** or p***?

Comment: @Hernán: It should be `sizeof pTemp`.

Comment: @KerrekSB yes, you're correct. In his case, 4 will work to read a DWORD from memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void * src_addr = reinterpret_cast<void *>(baseAddress);
std::size_t n;

if (ReadProcessMemory(handle, src_addr, &pTemp, sizeof pTemp, &n))
{
    if (n == sizeof pTemp)
    {
        std::cout << "Success: pTemp = " << pTemp << "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "We only read " << n << " bytes, not the expected "
                  << sizeof pTemp << " bytes.\n";
    }
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Failed to read process memory.\n";
}
```